# How to sort items by date in Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

How to sort items by date in Package Explorer in Eclipse? Is this possible?

[image]

Currently it sorts alphabetically. I want my last touched projects to be top or bottom.

Comment: Probably should make that an answer, @greg-449 .

Comment: Isn't there still no solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

You can use Working Sets at the top level to split things up but you can't change the sort.

You might also be able to use the task-focused features of `Mylyn` (an optional Eclipse component) to filter the view.